# iphone objective c Password validation shouldnot be less thn 6 characters

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *password=txt_pass.text;

NSString *passwordRegex = @"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,32}$/";

NSPredicate *passwordTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex];

BOOL myPasswordMatchesRegx=[passwordTest evaluateWithObject:password];
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Whenver this code is running an alert is showing .i.e.the password validattion (BOOL) is returning false......So where i am wrong .please give a correct regex for password validation with minimum 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
NSString *passwordRegex = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,32}$";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of error in the regular expression.

- Remove the leading and trailing "/" characters.
- Change the minimum match length from 7 to 6.

Instead of a `NSPredicate` just use the `NSString` method:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
```

With the option: `NSRegularExpressionSearch`.

Example code:

```
NSString *passRegEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$";
NSRange range = [password rangeOfString: passRegEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL isValidPassword = range.location != NSNotFound;
NSLog(@"isValidPassword: %@", isValidPassword ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Valid test:

```
NSString * password = @"abcdefgh"; // example vaid password
NSString *passRegEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$";
NSRange range = [password rangeOfString: passRegEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL isValidPassword = range.location != NSNotFound;
NSLog(@"Password: '%@' is: %@", password, isValidPassword ? @"Valid" : @"inValid");
```

Output:

> Password: 'abcdefgh' is: valid

Invalid test:

```
NSString * password = @"abcfg"; // example short password
NSString *passRegEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,32}$";
NSRange range = [password rangeOfString: passRegEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL isValidPassword = range.location != NSNotFound;
NSLog(@"Password: '%@' is: %@", password, isValidPassword ? @"Valid" : @"inValid");
```

Output:

> Password: 'abcfg' is: inValid

See: ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: I tried with your code,.....Still bool is returning false,.....  I have a textfield to enter password..Whenever user clicks on it,has to enter minimum 6 characters,.Butthe pattern mismatching is occuring and bool is reurning false.Can you explain me y???? Secondly please explain BOOL isValidPassword=range.location!=NSFound.

Comment: `NSRange` has two components, `location` and `length`. When the match is not round `location` is set to the value `NSFound`. So if `length` is nit equal to `NSFound` the password is valid.